# NoReverseMatch while using get_absolute_url in Django

Tags: python, regex, django

Error Trace:

```
NoReverseMatch at /search/
    Reverse for '/about/murder-in-the-curtain' not found. '/about/murder-in-the-curtain' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=mur
    Django Version: 1.11.6
    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
    Exception Value:    
    Reverse for '/about/murder-in-the-curtain' not found. '/about/murder-in-the-curtain' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

URL Conf:

```
 url(r'^about/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', about_pages, name="about_pages")
```

Model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
        slug = models.SlugField(default = "")

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            reverse("about_pages", kwargs = {"slug" : self.slug})
```

Template:

```
{% for result in results %}
<a href = {% url result.get_absolute_url %}>{{result.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Is my regex alright?
I feel its generating the url correctly but not finding a matching pattern in URLConf to navigate to a view.

Answer (score 3):

The `get_absolute_url` method reverses the url and returns it, so you don't have to use the `{% url %}` tag with it. Change the template to:

```
<a href="{{ result.get_absolute_url }}">{{result.name}}</a>
```

Comment: It worked. Cant thank you enough. I've always wondered though, why do we reverse the url?

Comment: Reversing the url means you don't have to hardcode it everywhere. If you decide to change your urls so that the book url is `/books/murder-in-the-curtain`, then you won't have to change your `get_absolute_url` method because you have used `reverse` instead of hardcoding `/about/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href = {% url result.get_absolute_url %}>{{result.name}}</a>
```

you should not use it like that , because it's a method of Book, not url path ,

So you should write here

```
<a href = {{ result.get_absolute_url }}>{{result.name}}</a>
```